# Parsing Dynamic XML to SQL Server tables with Parent and child relation

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a XML in Source Table. I need to parse this XML to 3 different tables which has Parent Child relationship. I can do this in C# but currently for this i need to implement it at SQL server side.
The sample xml looks like:

```
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
     <HEADER_ID>5001507</HEADER_ID>
     <ORDER_NUMBER>42678548</ORDER_NUMBER>
     <CUST_PO_NUMBER>LSWQWE1</CUST_PO_NUMBER>
     <CUSTOMER_NUMBER>38087</CUSTOMER_NUMBER>
     <CUSTOMER_NAME>UNIVERSE SELLER</CUSTOMER_NAME>
     <LINE>
       <LINE_ROW>
         <HEADER_ID>5001507</HEADER_ID>
         <LINE_ID>12532839</LINE_ID>
         <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>        
         <ITEM_NUMBER>STAGEPAS 600I-CA</ITEM_NUMBER>
         <ORDER_QUANTITY>5</ORDER_QUANTITY>        
       </LINE_ROW>      
       <LINE_ROW>
         <HEADER_ID>5001507</HEADER_ID>
         <LINE_ID>12532901</LINE_ID>
         <LINE_NUMBER>3</LINE_NUMBER>        
         <ITEM_NUMBER>CD-C600 RK</ITEM_NUMBER>
         <ORDER_QUANTITY>6</ORDER_QUANTITY>
       </LINE_ROW>
       <LINE_ROW>
         <HEADER_ID>5001507</HEADER_ID>
         <LINE_ID>12532902</LINE_ID>
         <LINE_NUMBER>4</LINE_NUMBER>
         <ITEM_NUMBER>CD-S300 RK</ITEM_NUMBER>
         <ORDER_QUANTITY>8</ORDER_QUANTITY>
      </LINE_ROW>      
    </LINE>
    <PRCADJ>
      <PRCADJ_ROW>
        <PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_ID>43095064</PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_ID>
        <HEADER_ID>5001507</HEADER_ID>
        <LINE_ID>12532839</LINE_ID>        
        <ADJUSTED_AMOUNT>-126</ADJUSTED_AMOUNT>
      </PRCADJ_ROW>
      <PRCADJ_ROW>
        <PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_ID>43095068</PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_ID>
        <HEADER_ID>5001507</HEADER_ID>
        <LINE_ID>12532840</LINE_ID>
        <ADJUSTED_AMOUNT>-96.6</ADJUSTED_AMOUNT>
      </PRCADJ_ROW>          
    </PRCADJ>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

The issue is the Parent can have multiple child and each child can multiple sub child. How can i write query to transfer this into Sql Server 2005

Comment: What attempts have you made?

Comment: @Shweetha, was the answer helpful, you can accept if it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use three `CROSS APPLY` operators to break up the "list of XML elements" into separate pseudo tables of XML rows, so you can access their properties - something like this:

```
SELECT
    HeaderID = XCRow.value('(HEADER_ID)[1]', 'int'),
    OrderNumber = XCRow.value('(ORDER_NUMBER)[1]', 'int'),
    LineHeaderID = XCLine.value('(HEADER_ID)[1]', 'int'),
    LineID = XCLine.value('(LINE_ID)[1]', 'int'),
    LineNumber = XCLine.value('(LINE_NUMBER)[1]', 'int'),
    PriceAdjustmentID = XCPrc.value('(PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_ID)[1]', 'int'),
    AdjustedAmount = XCPrc.value('(ADJUSTED_AMOUNT)[1]', 'decimal(20,4)')
FROM 
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
CROSS APPLY
    Data.nodes('/ROWSET/ROW') AS XTRow(XCRow)
CROSS APPLY
    XCRow.nodes('LINE/LINE_ROW') AS XTLine(XCLine)
CROSS APPLY
    XCRow.nodes('PRCADJ/PRCADJ_ROW') AS XTPrc(XCPrc)
```

With this, the first `CROSS APPLY` will handle all the elements that are found directly under `<ROWSET> / <ROW>` (the header information), the second one will enumerate all instances of `<LINE> / <LINE_ROW>` below that header element, and the third `CROSS APPLY` handles the `<PRCADJ> / <PRCADJ_ROW>` elements, also below the header.

You might need to tweak the outputs a bit - and I only picked two or three of the possible values - extend and adapt to your own needs! But this should show you the basic mechanism - the `.nodes()` method returns a "pseudo table" of XML fragments, one for each match of the XPath expression you define.

Answer (score 1):

you can do some thing like this. using `cross apply` you will get node elements and then extract the value using `value` clause. you need to specify the column type i.e int or varchar etc.

The result can then be inserted using `insert into select` query.

```
insert into Table1 values ( header_id, order_number, cust_po_number)
select R.value('(HEADER_ID)[1]', 'int') As header_id,
       R.value('(ORDER_NUMBER)[1]', 'int') as order_number,
       R.value('(CUST_PO_NUMBER)[1]', 'varchar(256)') as cust_po_number
from table 
cross apply XMLdata.nodes('/ROWSET/ROW') AS P(R)

insert into Table2 values ( header_id, line_id, line_number)
select R.value('(HEADER_ID)[1]', 'int') As header_id,
       R.value('(LINE_ID)[1]', 'int') as line_id,
       R.value('(LINE_NUMBER)[1]', 'int') as line_number
from table 
cross apply XMLdata.nodes('/ROWSET/ROW/LINE/LINE_ROW') AS P(R)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However due to slight change in the requirements i want to mention that the xml nodes will change. So how can i accommodate this dynamism. For example Header might have Order no and at time the node will not be there at all.